# Preventing input type=image from sending mouse coordinates

Tags: html

Is there anyway I can prevent the input type=image from sending the mouse coordinates during form submission.

Thanks,
Sivakumar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so, since that's the entire point of that element.

If you don't want the mouse coordinates, could you not change to use a standard `<input type="submit">`, and simply style it to use the same image?

Comment: Yup, disabling borders and setting a CSS `background-image` along with a `width` and `height` should work.